# yocto core-image-sato gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad QA Issue

Tags: x11, yocto

During building `core-image-sato` on Yocto  sumo distro for pcDuino3 using `meta-sunxi` I get the following QA error during finalizing `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`:

```
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so contained in package gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opengl requires libGLESv2.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opengl? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so contained in package gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opengl requires libEGL.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opengl? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libgstgl-1.0.so.0.1204.0 contained in package libgstgl-1.0 requires libEGL.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libgstgl-1.0? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libgstgl-1.0.so.0.1204.0 contained in package libgstgl-1.0 requires libGLESv2.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libgstgl-1.0? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.12.4-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
```

My `local.conf` file contains

```
PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-xserver-xorg = "glamor"
IMAGE_FEATURES += "x11"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl x11"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "wayland"
```

It seems that I forgot to add a few *.so library as an error suggest. Unfortunately, I still learn Yocto and don't know many things and packages dependencies. In the end, I add that processes "do_conifugre, do_compile, do_package" done success but stuck on generating "do_package do_package_write_ipk". How to add missing dependencies?

Comment: `libGLESv2` and `libEGL` are provided by `mesa`. Is mesa already part of your image?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried something like DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl x11 mesa". The result was the same. Maybe I add it to the wrong place.

Comment: Additionall I included sunxi-mali.inc which conatins PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/mesa ?= "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgl ?= "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles1 ?= "sunxi-mali"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles2 ?= "sunxi-mali"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/egl ?= "sunxi-mali"

XSERVER += "sunxi-mali \
            sunxi-mali-dev"

MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "\
 kernel-module-mali \
 kernel-module-mali-drm \
  "